# jQuery error: missing ( before formal parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have this jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function{
    $("#btnLogon").bind("click", function(){
      $("#btnLogon").after('<span class="error">Please wait...</span>');
    });
  });

</script>
```

In Firebug I get the error message

```
missing ( before formal parameters
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function{
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLogon").bind("click", function(){
        $("#btnLogon").after('<span class="error">Please wait...</span>');
    });
});
</script>
```

You were missing the parentheses after `function`, on the second line.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the empty parameter list in the anonymous function for the ready handler on the document.

You can also use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) as a shortcut to [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

You can also use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) in your handler function, rather than select from the DOM again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLogon").click(function(e){
        $(e.target).after('<span class="error">Please wait...</span>');
    });
});
```